# TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a array like this

```
var users = [
    { 'id': 1, 'name': 'user name', 'age': 25, ... }, 
    { 'id': 2, 'name': 'user name', 'age': 25, ... } 
    ...
]
```

I use `ng-repeat` to display it as a list. like so.

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users">
    {{user.name}}
    <a href="#" ng-click="UserCTRL.remove_user(user.id)">remove user</a>
</li>
```

And I made the `li` sortable using jquery sortable. The `sortable` works and `remove_user` works. But when I move the last li to any position above it works until i try to remove user then I get the error.

I appreciate any help. what does the error mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524978/jquery-ui-sortable-maintain-sortable-helper-as-list-changes-when-dragging Check this out, it seems you have to lock the list.

Comment: Why do you use jQuery `sortable`? AngularJS has sorting already built in. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Comment: @fdomig I want to the user to sort user list(by drag and drop) the user in the list to his own preference. then I save the new position.

Comment: @HenkJansen I tried it without the angularjs it works. I think angularjs is throwing the error

Answer (score 4):

I dont know if you solve this error for this question was raised 2 years ago. I happened to get the error just like you, and I guess the error might be `Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null`. Adding wrap layer `div` inside the `ng-repeat` to prevent the angular element been messed and sort it by operate with the `div` just added list like the following should prevent this error:

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users">
    <div>
        {{user.name}}
        <a href="#" ng-click="UserCTRL.remove_user(user.id)">remove user</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur due to extensions installed in the browser. I was getting the same error when 'Dark Reader' extension was enabled in the chrome browser.